Switching 3.3V with 3.3V signal
I'm designing a circuit that uses a Seeed Xiao ESP32C3 and a DFPlayer Mini MP3 player. The ESP32C3 has a battery input and a regulated 3V3 output, and the DFPlayer takes 3.3V power, so that would seem to be a straightforward way to power the circuit.
However, I've read discussions (1, 2) that the DFPlayer draws 20 mA even when idle. I'd prefer not to drain the battery so quickly, so I'm trying to find a way to gate its power based on a signal from the ESP32C3. I measured the DFPlayer consuming up to 75 mA when running, and the ESP32C3's GPIO pins can't source that much current, so I'm trying to use a MOSFET to gate the regulated 3V3 output.
I read a bunch of posts (1, 2, 3, 4) trying to figure out what MOSFET to get. I wound up looking for N-channel logic level MOSFETs with R_ds(on) explicitly specified (and very small) for V_gs = ~3.3V. I tried four parts, using the GPIO as the gate voltage (3.22V from GPIO to ground), and measured the voltage from source to ground - and none of them was anywhere near fully on:

IRLB4132PbF: voltage from source to ground was 1.64V
PSMN4R3-30PL: 1.69V
IRF3708 clone: 1.68V
PMV16XNR: 2.50V

All of them turned fully on (3.28V) if I manually applied the 5V output of the ESP32C3 to the gate.
This is the circuit I've been using for taking measurements:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
The dashed-line box is where the DFPlayer would go; I've put an LED there to keep things simple.
So at this point I suspect I'm just misunderstanding something. I'm a software guy at heart, and I'm very much bumbling around and trying to learn when it comes to anything analog. Concrete suggestions and clarifications would be very welcome.

For MOSFET switching applications, the source terminal should be connected to the "switched" rail, i.e. the positive supply for P-channel and ground for N-channel; yours is backwards.
Furthermore, for devices that have I/O pins like your MP3 module, switching the supply with a P-channel device is preferred since there may be other paths to ground that could cause undesirable operation when it's supposed to be "off".
I suggest using a P-channel MOSFET on the high side of your device. The ESP32 will have to drive or let the gate float high to turn off the MP3 module but that shouldn't be a problem.

Thanks! The bit about other paths to ground is something I wouldn't have thought of.
About having the gate float high to turn off the MP3 module - I wonder if that will be an issue when the ESP32 is initializing? I don't know what the power-on state of the pins would be.

It looks like you are trying to use an N-channel mosfet as a high-side switch, which cannot work unless you have a gate voltage above the 'controlled' voltage. So using 5V works as you have found. If you measure gate-source voltage, you will see it is only 1.7V even though you are using a 5V signal. The source is rising up to 3.3V due to the load.
The important thing is that the gate needs to be a few volts above the source. A N-channel mosfet is better suited as a low-side switch. In this case, the 'placeholder' goes between 3.3V and the drain; the source connects directly to ground. Since the source is directly connected to ground, an IO pin should easily be able to provide enough V to the gate to turn the mosfet on.
This arrangement should work fine for your simple 'placeholder' arrangement, but might not if you also have other IO pins connected to the DFPlayer to control it.

That totally makes sense, thanks. When I was writing up my post, I thought "hmm, I'm measuring the voltage from gate to ground, not gate to source", but I didn't pay attention to my confusion.
And yes, there will be other IO pins on the DFPlayer, so I may need to use a P-channel mosfet.

I'm not familiar with the DFPlayer, but if it uses a 3.3V serial interface as per Spehro Pefhany's answer, then these IO pins would naturally sit high when idle. In such a case, a low side switch will allow everything to be pulled high when the mosfet is off. Of course, there may be other connections that make a high-side switch easier to implement too (eg connections to a speaker/amp).

Something like this should work for you:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
You should drive the outputs from the ESP32 low before turning off the module and make sure they are low before turning it on. The resistors are there to save you from a destructive latchup event even if you forget or have a code issue.
If you (for example) have TXD high when the the module is powered down, then current will flow through the ESD protection circuitry in the module chip.
If the current is high enough, when power is applied that can cause latchup which can destroy the chip.
With the resistors, a few mA can flow if you don't drive any outputs from the MCU low, which will result in wasted current drain even if it does not cause dramatic issues.

Thanks. This is another subtle point that wouldn't have occurred to me...
